# How can i force Angular load third party libraries at startup when i do not use angular builders

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

As everyone knows, in angular.json file there are configuration which configures builders for development or production. each builder config has a property called **scripts** which is responsible to load external scripts before any part of angular is loaded.

I have a case where i do not use any integrated builders. instead i have configured my own webpack builders for production also for development.

Therefore i am not able to tell compiler that use script property to load anything. but i need these third party libraries to be loaded before anything of angular.

Is there any other way to tell angular via webpack configuration or native way to load script the same way it would load via scripts ?

Comment: A work around can be lazy load the external library, read is this link of Netanel https://netbasal.com/loading-external-libraries-on-demand-in-angular-9dad45701801

Comment: Yea but in my case that will not work. because i need these scripts to be loaded at the very first. Yes, one option would be to use promises and load those scripts and use onload method then resolve all of them and write logic in scope but it is not comfortable. that will be widely used. I do not like that i have hard coded it in index.html.